# How can I handle circular reference error in powerapps when trying to filter selections of two comboboxes depending on each other?

Tags: checkbox, circular-reference, powerapps

I am using PowerApps to create a small app which contains two `comboboxes`, which filter information that are being displayed on a `data table` and come from an excel sheet called `Table`. More specifically, my first combobox is called `ColorCombo` and displays distinct values, which come from the column `Color` of the sheet `Table` and the second combobox is called `SizeCombo` and displays distinct values that are contained on the column `Size` of the `Table`

My goal is to filter the information of the one combobox depending on the selection of the other combobox.

For instance, I have the colors : `[Red, Blue,Green]` listed on the `ColorCombo` and the sizes: `[32,34,36]` listed on the `SizeCombo`. If the red color is only available on size 32 then when I select the red option on the colorcombo I want to only see the number 32 on the `SizeCombo` and if the size 32 is available on green and blue color then when I select it on the `SizeCombo` I want to only see the options green and blue on the `ColorCombo`. The code I have so far is:

```
Sort(Distinct(Filter(Table, If(CountRows(ColorCombo.SelectedItems) = 0,true, 
Size in SizeCombo.SelectedItems)),Color),Result,Ascending)
```

which works ok for the colorcombo. When I add the same statement for the SizeCombo as well though, I get an circular reference error. This is the statement I input:

```
Sort(Distinct(Filter(Table, If(CountRows(SizeCombo.SelectedItems) = 0,true, 
Color in ColorCombo.SelectedItems)),Size),Result,Ascending)
```

I understand that this is happening because the selection of the comboboxes are depending on each other recursively, so this happens to prevent an infinite loop, but how could I solve this? I appreciate any help you can provide, since I have been trying to find a solution to it since a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick workarounds could be implemented via UI/UX:

- Force the user to go through the two boxes sequentially

  - Start with `sizecombo` (for example).
  - Set DisplayMode of `colorcombo` to `If(IsBlank(Size.Selected.Value), DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit`
  - Adjust the code accordingly.
- Another idea: Instead of two comboboxes, have user select a size, then display swatches of `Available Colors` in a small Gallery. Or vice versa, choose a color then display `Available Sizes`.
- You could accomplish that pretty easily using `Filter()`